Adding github secrets to CI/CD actions to Vercel deployment
I want to build and deploy my NextJS app to Vercel with environments from github secrets (not from env file or from vercel directly).
Here is my workflow (a development one):
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - development

jobs:
  Deploy-Development:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Configure node
        uses: ./.github/actions/setup-project

      - name: Format & Lint code
        uses: ./.github/actions/format-code

      - name: Build app
        run: npm run build
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.DEV_DATABASE_URL }}
          NEXTAUTH_SECRET: ${{ secrets.NEXTAUTH_SECRET }}
          NEXT_ENV: 'development'

      - name: Deploy app to Vercel development env
        uses: ./.github/actions/vercel-deployment
        with:
          mode: 'development'
          vercel-token: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
        env:
          VERCEL_ORG_ID: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_ORG_ID }}
          VERCEL_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_PROJECT_ID }}
          VERCEL_FORCE_NO_BUILD_CACHE: 1
          DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.DEV_DATABASE_URL }}
          NEXTAUTH_SECRET: ${{ secrets.NEXTAUTH_SECRET }}
          API_KEY: ${{ secrets.API_KEY }}
          NEXT_ENV: 'development'

and below is my action:
inputs:
  vercel-token:
    description: 'Vercel token'
    required: true
  mode:
    description: 'Deployment mode'
    required: true

runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - name: Install Vercel CLI
      run: npm install --global vercel@canary
      shell: bash

    - name: PRODUCTION Vercel Deployment
      if: ${{ inputs.mode == 'production' }}
      run: |
        vercel pull --yes --environment=production --token=${{ inputs.vercel-token }}
        vercel build --prod --token=${{ inputs.vercel-token }}
        vercel deploy --prebuilt --prod --token=${{ inputs.vercel-token }}
      shell: bash

    - name: DEVELOPMENT Vercel Deployment
      if: ${{ inputs.mode == 'development' }}
      run: |
        vercel pull --yes --environment=development --token=${{ inputs.vercel-token }}
        vercel build --token=${{ inputs.vercel-token }}
        vercel deploy --prebuilt --token=${{ inputs.vercel-token }}
      shell: bash

What changes should I make to inject proper variables? I want to have different database on development mode and production mode. I know there is a env hierarchy with NextJS.

You could create two GitHub environments
Then define environment variables for each environment.
Then set
environment: development

or
environment: production

on the deployment step.
It will see environment variables set on the environment.

I have already defined my environment variables inside GH secrets.
I pass them, for instance, here as a development mode:
DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.DEV_DATABASE_URL }}
but Vercel doesn't build the application with expected env.
Could you provide an example of your solution?
